# Attach Domain Name to private internal IP with GCP terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hi I am to create a DNS record for my DNS zone so I can set up ssh to via hostname instead of an IP address. I can't quite get terraform to create the domain name for my use case. How can I get it to work? I can't find the right value for rrdatas. The IP for the internal address is arbitrary as long as it's on the subnet specified for the VM.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "tyler_test_vm_instance" {
   count = var.node_count
   name = "jenkins-worker-test-${count.index}"
   machine_type = "n2-standard-2"
   min_cpu_platform = "Intel Ice Lake"
   attached_disk {
     source = google_compute_disk.jenkins_data_disk.*.id[count.index]
     device_name = "jenkins-data-test"
   }
   attached_disk {
       source = google_compute_disk.docker_data_disk.*.id[count.index]
       device_name = "docker-data-test"

   }

   lifecycle {
       create_before_destroy = true
       ignore_changes = [
         attached_disk
       ]
   }

   service_account { 
       email = "example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
       scopes = ["cloud-platform"]

   }
   
   boot_disk {
       initialize_params {
           image = "ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20220805"
       }
   }

   network_interface {
       network = var.gcp_project_network_name
       subnetwork = var.subnet_name
   }
   metadata_startup_script = "${file(var.startup_script)}"
}


resource "google_dns_record_set" "rs" {
   count = var.node_count
   name = "jenkins-worker-test-${count.index}.com"
   type = "A"
   ttl = 300
   managed_zone = "corp-org-com"
#no idea what goes in rrdatas. None of these work.
   #rrdatas = ["jenkins-worker-test-${count.index}.com"]
   rrdatas = [google_compute_instance.tyler_test_vm_instance.*.id[count.index].network_interface.network.network_ip]
   #rrdatas = [google_compute_instance.tyler_test_vm_instance.*.id[count.index].network_interface[0]]
}
```

Comment: The internal IP address of the instance is `network_interface.0.network_ip`

Comment: Are you trying to configure a Private DNS, is this your end goal to attach your domain to an internal IP address?

Comment: The internal IP can be ephemeral. I want to be able to attach a domain name to the internal ephemeral IP. But yes that is my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong rrdatas and was using the wrong record for the name.

I should of been using "jenkins-worker-test-${count.index}.corp.domain.com." This needed a . at the end.
and rrdatas should have looked like this.
rrdatas = [google_compute_instance.tyler_test_vm_instance.*[count.index].network_interface.0.network_ip]

Once I changed these values I was able to get everything to work.

Comment: Can you rewrite your answer into Terraform HCL? As written we have to figure out what you changed.

Comment: Great! Just an added information. You can use this link https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dns_record_set as a template for GCP terraform. 

Once you are on the link just look on Cloud DNS click dropdown menu then choose “google dns record set.” From there it will show you samples of terraform templates on how to add a record set.